# Realm gets NullPointerException when I try to delete in Android

Tags: android, realm

I have an Android app that shows a routes in a map, I receive the data from my own web services in JSON like this:

The "available" fields indicates if this routes is still active (true) or no (false). My code is the following:

If the route is active is necessary create or uptade (if just exists)

```java
if(json.getBoolean("available") == true)
{
    synchronized(realm){
        realm.beginTransaction();
        Ruta ruta = realm.where(Ruta.class).equalTo("id", json.getLong("id")).findFirst();

        //If doesn't exists we create a new route else I clear the coordinates to add news
        if(ruta == null){
            ruta = realm.createObject(Ruta.class); // Create a new object
        }else{
            ruta.getCoordenadas().clear();
        }

        ruta.setNombre(json.getString("name"));
        ruta.setType_id(json.getInt("type_id"));

        final JSONArray jsonCoordenadas = json.getJSONArray("coordinates");
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonCoordenadas.length(); i++){

            final JSONObject jsonCoordenada = jsonCoordenadas.getJSONObject(i);
            Coordenada coordenadas = realm.createObject(Coordenada.class);
            coordenadas.setLat(jsonCoordenada.getDouble("lat"));
            coordenadas.setLon(jsonCoordenada.getDouble("lon"));
            ruta.getCoordenadas().add(coordenadas);
        }
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

And works perfect.

Else "available" == false, it's time to delete.

```java
else
{
    synchronized(realm){
        final Ruta ruta = realm.where(Ruta.class)
                 .equalTo("id", json.getLong("id"))
                 .findFirst();
        if(ruta != null)
        {
            realm.beginTransaction();
            if(ruta.getCoordenadas().size() > 0)
                ruta.getCoordenadas().clear();
            ruta.removeFromRealm();
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    }
}

//If I create, update or delete I Save the last update Date of routes 
synchronized(realm){
    realm.beginTransaction();
    change.setCod(changeBdd);
    Log.e("changeBdd",changeBdd);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

And this not work, if I do this for first time, REALM "delete" the route, but if I received the same Json for second time right now after delete. REALM find again the route, but when try to destroy crush the app.

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.mapApp.ActivityPrincipal$CargaRutas.doInBackground(ActivityPrincipal.java:555)
at com.app.mapApp.ActivityPrincipal$CargaRutas.doInBackground(ActivityPrincipal.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

Plus all of this is inside of AsyncTask specifically in the method doInBackground

```java
private class CargaRutas extends AsyncTask<ItemRuta, ItemRuta, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(ItemRuta... items) {
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

I don't know How can I fix that, any one help me??? I use REALM 0.76.0

Comment: What does that title mean?

Comment: Ok I changed the title

Answer (score 2):

See this section in the Realm Docs: [Using a Realm across Threads](http://realm.io/docs/java/0.79.0/#using-a-realm-across-threads)

> The only rule to using Realm across threads is to remember that Realm, RealmObject or RealmResults instances cannot be passed across threads. When you want to access the same data from a different thread, you should simply obtain a new Realm instance (i.e. Realm.getInstance(Context context) or its cousins) and get your objects through a query. The objects will map to the same data on disk, and will be readable & writeable from any thread!

[Here's an example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/threadExample) of how to access Realm data across multiple threads.

Hope this helps.